# How can I prevent matplotlib from plotting the floating point variation of an array of similar values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.ones(1000)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

gives:
[image]

but

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.ones(1000) + np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1E-12, size=1000)
plt.plot(x, y)
```

gives:
[image]

This seems like unexpected behavior, being that I did not change any keyword arguments to plot. How do I get the second y value to plot like the first one even though there is some floating point variation among the array values?

Comment: I don't get how this is unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Just because it isn't unexpected for you doesn't mean it might be unexpected for someone else.

Comment: But I would find it very unexpected if I got your first graph that just rounded all my raw data without me asking it to. I was not being standoffish; I want to understand what makes this unexpected to you, then perhaps we can address that.

Comment: This is at least by far less unexpected than the inverse, which would be plotting a highly oscillating signal and seeing a straight line only. So I think the autoscaling done by matplotlib is in general very well working. Is this question about how to show both plots on the same scale or is it about explaining the autoscaling?

Comment: The first plot seems to use a different y limit autoscaling rule as the second plot. The first array has no floating point variation among the values and matplotlib seems to choose y limits that are some percentage of the (maybe) mean of the values. The second plot seems to subtract 1.0 from the array, autoscale to show the min/max of the data, and uses a notation I'm not familiar with "1E-12+1" which seems to indicate that 1.0 was subtracted from the array. It isn't obvious that the two plots simply differ in y limit scaling.

Comment: To put the notation "1e-12+1" into words it means: append 1e-12 to the y tick value and then add 1 to it, to get the actual value of the data.

Comment: If you assume that the autoscaling by default scales to ~110% of the difference in data shown, it is quite clear that for a constant value, this will not work and some fall-back needs to be used for cases where a single value is shown, right?

Comment: Sure, but what isn't clear is why the mean is subtracted from the data in the second plot and a less-than-obvious notation is added to the top of the graph.

Comment: The way matplotlib shows the data seems pretty reasonable to me. If you're not happy with that, how would you plot it instead? And what would you show on the axes?

Comment: I would have the second plot have y-limits equal to 110% * (1 - ~3E-12) to 110% * (1 + ~3E-12) and do away with the subtraction of the (assumingly) mean value. The first plot would stay as is. Finally, the autoscale documentation and the plot documentation could elucidate the autoscaling rules. If these were the case, I doubt I would have been confused. Or as an alternative, the plot documentation states clearly what to expect wrt to autoscaling and leave it as is.

Comment: And also, I don't disagree that what matplotlib already does is reasonable. It simply isn't obvious what it is doing and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to keep the same yrange and crop the points falling out of `[0.95, 1.05]`?

```
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([0.95, 1.05])
```

By default, matplotlib sets the x and y ranges so that every point is displayed (see [autoscale](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html)).

But no, matplotlib (or numpy, for that matter) will not magically truncate or round floats if they are close enough to an integer. This would display wrong values and be *really* unexpected.

The [zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) specifies that :

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: This corrects the plot and is a solution. Now I see that the second plot has the y limits autoscaled to show all points whereas the first plot is autoscaled with a different rule.

Comment: This is the solution to my explicit question. Thanks.